# Extjs 4, how to convert a form data into xml format?

Tags: xml, extjs, encoding

In the Extjs 4, how to convert a form data into XML format? Does it have a similar method as JSON, like `Ext.JSON.encode()`?

Thanks

Comment: This might help: http://www.objis.com/formationextjs/lib/extjs-4.0.0/docs/api/Ext.data.reader.Xml.html

Answer (score 0):

No, there is nothing built in to do this, you would need to roll your own.